# TIMESTAMPDIFF returns blob in mysql

Tags: mysql

I am having a problem in my query, I want to display the two tables and group it by same date, then, add the difference of start and end time. Here's my tables:

**equipment_schedule**

```
id     |     equipment_id     |     booked_date     |     created_at              |     updated_date
1      |     1                |     2016-11-21      |     2016-11-21 21:21:21     |     2016-11-21 21:21:21
2      |     1                |     2016-11-22      |     2016-11-22 21:21:21     |     2016-11-22 21:21:21
3      |     1                |     2016-11-23      |     2016-11-23 21:21:21     |     2016-11-23 21:21:21
4      |     1                |     2016-11-24      |     2016-11-24 21:21:21     |     2016-11-24 21:21:21
5      |     1                |     2016-11-25      |     2016-11-25 21:21:21     |     2016-11-25 21:21:21
6      |     1                |     2016-11-26      |     2016-11-26 21:21:21     |     2016-11-26 21:21:21
7      |     1                |     2016-11-27      |     2016-11-27 21:21:21     |     2016-11-27 21:21:21
8      |     1                |     2016-11-28      |     2016-11-28 21:21:21     |     2016-11-28 21:21:21
9      |     1                |     2016-11-29      |     2016-11-29 21:21:21     |     2016-11-29 21:21:21
10     |     1                |     2016-11-30      |     2016-11-30 21:21:21     |     2016-11-30 21:21:21
```

**equipment_operation**

```
id     |     equipment_id     |     start_time               |     end_time                |     creation_date           |     updated_date
1      |     1                |     2016-11-21 09:20:00      |     2016-11-21 23:59:59     |     2016-11-21 09:00:00     |    2016-11-21 09:00:00
2      |     1                |     2016-11-22 09:20:00      |     2016-11-22 13:00:00     |     2016-11-22 09:00:00     |    2016-11-22 09:00:00
3      |     1                |     2016-12-01 09:20:00      |     2016-12-01 13:00:00     |     2016-12-01 09:00:00     |    2016-12-01 09:00:00
4      |     1                |     2016-11-22 14:00:00      |     2016-11-22 18:00:00     |     2016-11-22 14:00:00     |    2016-11-22 14:00:00
```

my query is this:

```
SELECT a.id, booked,
IF(a.diff = "diff", 0, a.diff) AS diff,
creation_date,
updated_date
FROM
(
    SELECT equipment_operation.id,
    (
        SELECT IF (DATE_FORMAT(equipment_operation.creation_date, "%m-%d-%Y") = DATE_FORMAT(booked_date, "%m-%d-%Y"), booked_date, 0)
        FROM equipment_schedule WHERE DATE_FORMAT(equipment_schedule.created_at, "%m-%d-%Y") = DATE_FORMAT(equipment_operation.creation_date, "%m-%d-%Y")
    ) AS booked, SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)) AS diff,
    equipment_operation.creation_date as creation_date, equipment_operation.updated_date as updated_date FROM equipment_operation
    INNER JOIN equipment_schedule ON (equipment_schedule.equipment_id = equipment_operation.equipment_id)
    GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(equipment_operation.creation_date, "%m-%d-%Y")
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id, booked_date, "diff", created_at as creation_date, updated_at as updated_date FROM equipment_schedule
) a
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(a.creation_date, "%m-%d-%Y")
```

the diff returns blob, but when I remove the sum it will return the difference of start_time and end_time in seconds but it will give a wrong query because it is not added with the same date.

my output:

```
id  |  booked      |  diff  |  creation_date        |   updated_date
1   |  2016-11-21  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-21 09:00:00  |   2016-11-21 09:00:00
2   |  2016-11-22  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-22 09:00:00  |   2016-11-22 09:00:00
3   |  2016-11-23  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-23 05:58:09  |   2016-11-23 05:58:09
4   |  2016-11-24  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-24 05:58:16  |   2016-11-24 05:58:16
5   |  2016-11-25  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-25 05:58:16  |   2016-11-25 05:58:16
6   |  2016-11-26  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-26 05:58:17  |   2016-11-26 05:58:17
7   |  2016-11-27  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-27 01:56:19  |   2016-11-27 01:56:19
8   |  2016-11-28  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-28 01:56:19  |   2016-11-28 01:56:19
9   |  2016-11-29  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-29 01:57:34  |   2016-11-29 01:57:34
10  |  2016-11-30  |  BLOB  |  2016-11-30 01:58:17  |   2016-11-30 01:58:17
3   |  null        |  BLOB  |  2016-12-01 09:00:00  |   2016-12-01 09:00:00
```

my expected output is that the diff has a value.

Comment: Please show us your expected output.

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: What are the types of the `start_time` and `end_time` columns?

Comment: datetime that's why I have to format it. If you have a better solution and not complicated, it would be good. I need it now.

Comment: You should not be getting a BLOB result.

Comment: when I remove the sum function, it will give a result but not exact because there's the same date in equipment_operation and i have to sum it.

Comment: Your query has a problem: You are selecting non-aggregate column in your `SELECT` clause which do not appear in the `GROUP BY`clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the problem with your query:

```
SELECT id, booked_date, "diff", ...
                         ^^^
```

You are performing a `UNION` between two tables, and in the first half of the union you have the sum of integers for the `diff` column while in the second half you have a string.  In general, it is required that the types of *all* the columns are in agreement.  One way around this would be to cast your timestamp difference term as `char`, i.e.

```
CAST(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)) AS CHAR(5)) AS diff,
```

**Update:**

If you are having problems with the above cast, you can try the following alternative:

```
CONCAT(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)), '') AS diff,
```

or try padding the left of the number with spaces:

```
LPAD(CAST(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)) AS CHAR(5)), 5, ' ') AS diff,
```

Comment: I get it, but it will display wrong result. in the id = 1, the diff must be 52799 but it will return 527990, the same with others, it will add a 0 in the last digit.

Comment: Are you certain that your expected data is correct.  Do this: run the original first half of the union query by itself and check the values.  Then calculate by hand.  Compare both against what my answer would give you.  Casting should _not_ be randomly adding zeroes.

Comment: I did what you said, it will add zero in the last digit. I don't know why, and this is my first time to use the cast. in your CAST, I remove the comma before AS CHAR(50) because it throws an error.

Comment: I can make it work by limiting the CHAR to 5 since, the 24 hours return 86400 seconds which is 5 digit only.

Comment: There's a problem in my solution. 1 hour is equivalent to 3600 seconds which is 4 digit.

Comment: @SeeMore I gave you an alternative in my answer.  I hope this works for you.

Comment: It adds 0 using concat, the result is the same when using cast. :(

Comment: Hmm...can you try using `SELECT id, booked_date, "diff "`... add a space after the last F in `diff`, and then cast your sum as `CHAR(5)` as you were doing before?  I think maybe your diff column is being treated as having a width of 4.

Comment: Nothing's changed. Is there an alternative way to subtract two time and convert it to second?

Comment: Please go to Fiddle and create a reproducible example: http://sqlfiddle.com/ ... I cannot reproduce your problem locally

Comment: I think the problem is it gets the highest length for example; i have 2400 and 27000. It will get the digit of 27000 which is 5 then do it all in the CAST, that's why the 2400 become 24000.

Comment: Please create a reproducible Fiddle for us to see.  Until then, I can't comment any further.

Comment: in id = 1, the diff must be 2400 not 24000.

Comment: Thanks for the Fiddle, but it doesn't seem to show the problem.  Your query is invalid, because it's selecting non-aggreate columns.  Please fix the query, the update the Fiddle.  You can't do this: `SELECT a.id, booked, ...` because these columns don't appear in `GROUP BY`.  Your query is NOT doing what you think it is.

Comment: it should be 2400 not 24000. since the difference between 9:20 and 10:00 is 40 minutes equivalent to 2400 not 24000.

Comment: I make it work with substring, I omit the last digit. SUBSTRING(CAST(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)) as CHAR(50)), 1, CHAR_LENGTH(CAST(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, start_time, end_time)) as CHAR(50))) - 1) AS diff. Thank you sir for the help. :)